# Build pixel shader project in VS2022

Tags: visual-studio, hlsl, fragment-shader, msbuild-task

I have an old class library project that was building fine in a previous version of Visual Studio (2017 IIRC). The project contains an HLSL-based pixel shader that generates a radial color picker. I have just ported it to VS2022 and it is no longer building telling me that it cannot find a build task. Here is the error message:

> The "ShaderBuildTask.PixelShaderCompile" task could not be loaded from
> the assembly ShaderBuildTask, Version=1.0.3072.18169, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=44e467d1687af125. Could not load file or assembly
> 'ShaderBuildTask, Version=1.0.3072.18169, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=44e467d1687af125' or one of its dependencies. The
> system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the 
> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are
> available, and that the task contains a public class that implements
> Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.AngularGradientShaderEffect

I have already installed the required shader compiler ([`ShaderBuildTaskSetup.msi`](https://github.com/midspace/SEToolbox/tree/master/Documentation)) on my machine. Reloading the project and restarting VS don't help either.

Has anyone used pixel shaders in VS2022 to see what I'm missing?

Comment: Do you have a small reproducible project for this?

Comment: @SimonMourier: Yeah, here is the [original project](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AslTlZyxpvziiwRieTFQ8ulBv4Eq?e=Fcj9Yn) that is causing trouble. The shared library installer is available inside the zip file that you must run on your end before building the project. You can (but don't have to) install project and item templates too.

Comment: My research so far suggests that this is a 32-bit build task and VS2022 uses 64-bit version of MSBuild, which doesn't play nice with old x86 build tasks. I have tried adding `Architecture="x86"` to the `UsingTask` node in the `.csproj` file, but that didn't help. MS guys [call it unfortunate](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/msbuild-and-64-bit-visual-studio-2022/) that we can't do anything in this regard about the tasks that we don't own.

Comment: Lastly, The original shader library project is no longer available anywhere on the Internet. After spending a whole lot of time, I was able to grab it from [archive.org](https://archive.org/download/sylirana_ms_codeplex_zips/tars/mscodeplex-w-4.tar/.%2Fwpfshadereffects.zip), but even that project is not building anymore, Someone else has also ported it to [github](https://github.com/garakutanokiseki/WPFPixelShaderEffectsLibrary), but this project too suffers from the same problem as mine.

Comment: You shouldn't need this legacy task. You can compile a .fx using fxc (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3dtools/fxc), just get rid of the old task, replace by this one:  `<Target Name="EffectCompile" Condition="'@(Effect)' != '' "><Exec Command="&quot;$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.22621.0\x64\fxc.exe&quot; /T ps_3_0 /Fo @(Effect -> '%(Filename).ps') @(Effect)"/></Target>` (fxc.exe path and arguments can vary depending on your setup and choices). full file https://pastebin.com/raw/pxBs0Smi

Comment: @SimonMourier: That would be very helpful, but for some reason, I can't locate `fxc.exe` on my machine (even though I have VS2022 installed). I'll see if I need to download Windows SDK separately. BTW, your pastebin link didn't work for me.

Comment: Yes, you need the Windows SDK installed. I've double checked pastebin link on other machines and it works fine.

Comment: @SimonMourier: Thanks a lot. That was it. My project finally builds. If you post this as answer, I'll happily award the bounty. That pastebin thing is probably because of some server-side restriction for my region. I see this problem about pastebin listed in many threads across the web.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `ShaderBuildTask` MsBuild task assembly that one can see used and talked about in various places on the Internet is dated more than 10 years ago and was written in C++ for an x86 processor. It also depends on files that may not be there or cannot be loaded easily today (DirectX9, etc.).

This assembly contains only one task wich is `PixelShaderCompile`. Its role is to take `.fx` files ("effect files") from a project (BTW not necessarily a C# project), compile them as `.ps` files (using the [D3DXCompileShader function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d9/d3dxcompileshader) or similar) and add them to the project as resources.

This work can be replaced by the Windows SDK's [Effect Compiler tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3dtools/fxc) (fxc.exe) and the [MsBuild Exec task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/exec-task). For example this task will compile all .fx files in the project as .ps file, just like `PixelShaderCompile` does:

```
<Exec Command="&quot;$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.22621.0\x64\fxc.exe&quot; /T ps_3_0 /Fo @(Effect -> '%(Filename).ps') @(Effect)"/>
```

Note the [Windows SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-sdk/) is required and the path must be adapted to its current version (here 10.0.22621.0).

So, to integrate this task you must:

1> Remove the

```
<UsingTask TaskName="ShaderBuildTask.PixelShaderCompile" AssemblyName="ShaderBuildTask, Version=1.0.3072.18169, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=44e467d1687af125" />
```

or similar line from the project file (here .csproj).

2> Replace the lines

```
<Target Name="EffectCompile" Condition="'@(Effect)' != '' ">
  <PixelShaderCompile Sources="@(Effect)">
    <Output TaskParameter="Outputs" ItemName="Resource" />
  </PixelShaderCompile>
</Target>
```

by something like this:

```
<Target Name="EffectCompile" Condition="'@(Effect)' != '' ">
  <Exec Command="&quot;$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.22621.0\x64\fxc.exe&quot; /T ps_3_0 /Fo %(Effect.RelativeDir)%(Effect.FileName).ps %(Effect.Identity)"/>

  <!-- Add this if you need to embed the file as WPF resources -->
  <ItemGroup>
    <Resource Include="%(Effect.RelativeDir)%(Effect.FileName).ps" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

Note one bonus benefit of this is you can tweak the `fxc.exe` command line to some specific needs which you coudn't do with the `PixelShaderCompile` task.

Comment: Tantalizingly close answer for me!  I'm getting "The command ...exited with code 1"  Further playing on the command line reveals I can do one file,but it chokes on multiple files.  I have
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.22621.0\x64\fxc.exe" /T ps_3_0 /Fo BandedSwirl.ps;Bloom.ps ShaderSource\BandedSwirl.fx;ShaderSource\Bloom.fx
which leads to 
an error occurred while setting the initial search directory.
searches will be relative to the application's starting directory.
compilation failed; no code produced

Comment: @Dave - I didn't really tested my command on multiple files . Can you try that one: `<Exec Command="&quot;$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.22621.0\x64\fxc.exe&quot; /T ps_3_0 /Fo %(Effect.Identity).ps %(Effect.Identity)"/>`instead

Comment: Thanks! I think that's handling multiple files now. Unfortunately, I'm now getting an error 
 error X3000: Illegal character in shader file
about 5 files in.  I suspect fxc and PixelShaderCompile have their differences....

Comment: Heads up to any future readers.  I was getting "illegal character in shader file..." because some of my *.fx files had encoding UTF-8-BOM instead of UTF-8.  Changed and now all compiling. I can only guess that PixelShaderCompile didn't care?   HUGE THANKS to @simon_mourier !